# Flying with medical equipment

Tags: international-travel, hand-luggage, batteries, medical-devices

I'll be traveling from the USA to Africa. Can I carry my portable ultrasound machine in checked baggage or will it need to be in my carry on due to the battery type?
The battery marked under Rating on the machine.
11.1V 2000mAh 22.2Wh

I'm using this exact machine:
https://valuestore.us/product/veterinary-ultrasound-scanner-v16-with-7-5-mhz-rectal-probe-3-5-mhz-convex-probe

Comment: What kind of battery and how big? Or if you do not know, which actual machine so someone can look it up?

Comment: Is the battery removable? Can you do an air shipment (FedEx, DHL, etc.)?

Comment: @Willeke im using this exact machine. https://valuestore.us/product/veterinary-ultrasound-scanner-v16-with-7-5-mhz-rectal-probe-3-5-mhz-convex-probe

Comment: @JonCuster yes the battery is removable. Shipping the battery or the machine Separate is not an option as shipping from here to africa would cost me a few hundred dollars just to send it plus an additional fee on that end i would have to pay

Comment: Given the size of the device, I would be surprised if the battery exceeded the limits in any way, but its capacity does not seem to be listed either in the webpage or in the manual, or, judging from the few photos available, on the device itself, so if someone checks you may have a hard time justifying it. As a side note I’m surprised by the lack of any FCC regulatory information.

Comment: Also note that what is apparently the exact same scanner is sold by the same seller for a much lower price, with free delivery in the US, on Amazon: https://www.amazon.com/Ultrasound-Scanner-Veterinary-Pregnancy-V16/dp/B083Z4PD6Q You can even have it shipped directly to Africa (not for free of course)

Comment: @jcaron thanks i bought this device months ago and it comes with two wands not just one like on amazon.

Comment: @jcaron the battery under Rating it says 11.1V 2000 mAh 22.2Wh is this safe for cargo or its better to carry on?

Answer (score 1):

ValueStore does not appear to publish the exact specifications of its batteries, but perhaps you can inspect yours to see if its capacity is printed anywhere on it.

[According to the FAA](https://www.faa.gov/hazmat/packsafe/lithium-batteries), lithium-ion batteries with a capacity of less than 100 Wh are allowed in your **carry-on luggage**. Probably your battery is indeed less than this capacity, but it is wise to check. Batteries between 100 and 160 Wh may also be allowed at the airline's discretion, so if you discover that your battery is in this range, you should contact your airline for further advice.

The policies for batteries in your **checked luggage are stricter** than those for carry-ons; in particular, you **may not** check any spare batteries, only batteries contained within devices. If you would prefer anyway to carry-on your device, you should definitely do so in order not to have to worry about these stricter policies. Review the FAA guidance linked above for further details.

Note that if your itinerary involves a connection, you will additionally have to comply with the aviation security policies of your onward travel. While most countries around the world have adopted broadly similar policies for lithium-ion batteries, if your battery is pushing the limits of the US policy, it would be still good to check to make sure you comply with all other relevant policies.

Comment: The IATA rules are described [here](https://www.iata.org/contentassets/6fea26dd84d24b26a7a1fd5788561d6e/passenger-lithium-battery.pdf). While each airline may diverge from this, I believe this is quite rare.